# Callback when NSView is added to NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow, key-value-observing

## Problem:

I am given a NSView from a third party library. When I am given the NSView it is not yet added to a NSWindow. I need to wait until the third party library adds the NSView to a NSWindow before executing some of my code. There is no method for the third party library to notify me when this happens. I need to check for this condition myself and I need the solution to work on OSX 10.9/10.10/10.11.

## What I Tried:

1. KVO on the "window" property in NSView. Works great but unfortunately the "window" property in NSView is not KVO compliant in OSX 10.9.
2. Spawn a thread and periodically check whether the "window" property on the NSView != nil. Unfortunately leads to some slight delay.

## Question:

Are there any KVO alternatives I can use for pre 10.10? Or any other solutions at all?

Comment: What do/can you do with the view? Subclass? Add subviews?

Comment: You could override `viewDidMoveToWindow()` or `viewWillMove(toWindow newWindow: NSWindow?)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I cannot subclass the view, it is given to me by the third party library (i.e. I don't control the instance). I can add subviews to it however (through addSubview) but I am unsure how it will help.

Comment: I think your guys suggestions may have clicked for me, I could possibly add a empty/invisible NSView as a subview which overrides viewDidMoveToWindow and execute my code inside that block. Will give it a go now!

Answer (score -1):

the not good way is create a NSTimer  to notice  that the view is added to the window

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is essentially what I am doing in option 2.